# on focus of every input and every time scroll top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

```
<div class="gdbox">
   <input id="one" type="text"><br><br>
   <input id="two" type="text"><br><br>
   <input id="one" type="text"><br><br><input type="text">
</div>
  <script>
  $('input').on('focus',function(){
     var inputHeight=$('.gdbox input').height();
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: inputHeight}, 600);
      return false;
   });
  </script>
```

now when ever i focus on the input body will scroll top it is working for only first time and one time focusing but i want "on focus of  every input and every time body,html should scroll top some what [see in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/YogeshDV/3p1orv40/3/)"

Comment: your filddle is not working .. this works   http://jsfiddle.net/YogeshDV/3p1orv40/3/

Answer (score 3):

You can use .offset().top for getting the top position of each element and then scroll it to top.

```
$('input').on('focus',function(){
    var inputHeight=$(this).offset().top;
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: inputHeight}, 600);
    return false;
 });
```

```js
$('input').on('focus',function(){
  var inputHeight=$(this).offset().top;
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: inputHeight}, 600);
    return false;
 });
```

```css
input{
  height:40px;
}

.gdbox
{
  height:600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gdbox">
    <div id="gdb1" class="gdbutton fontwhitenshadow">Q</div>
    <input id="one" type="text"><br><br>
    <input id="two" type="text"><br><br>
    <input id="one" type="text"><br><br><input type="text">
</div>


<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veniam beatae quas esse explicabo modi odio nesciunt vero error obcaecati ea sequi alias quam facilis delectus odit aperiam repellat similique corrupti.</div>
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/78ukreut/

Comment: Deep, (https://jsfiddle.net/78ukreut/ )   this is fine but  when ever i remove paragraph it wont work

Comment: @DVYogesh because once you remove paragraph there is no scroll on the page.

Comment: in mobile when ever i focus the in put ,keybord will come the user can not access next input keybord is hiding input

Comment: @DVYogesh let me check how it behaves on mobile.

Comment: @DVYogesh  I think for mobile the behavior will be like this only. Check the google sign up on mobile, it just set  the focused element position on the mobile screen and user will have to scroll to other fields manually.